# in which segment of the program are function pointers stored?

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

I wanted to know in which section of the program are function pointers stored? As in, is it on the program stack or is there a separate section for the same?

```
void f(void){}
int main(void){
 int x[10];
 void (*fp)(void) = NULL;
 fp = f;
 return 0;
}
```

Now, will the address of x and fp be in the same segment of the program's stack memory?

Answer (score 5):

A function pointer is no different from any other pointer in terms of storage, which is again no different from any other variable. So yes, they'll all be stored together in the same place, which is the stack for local variables.

Answer (score 1):

With a good compiler, they won't exist anywhere because their values are never used and contribute nothing to the output of the program.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this precise question is that your two examples (an array of ints and a pointer-to-a-function) are both local variables and both are kept on "the stack" (the stack is a bit conceptual but at the level of your question, it's the right way to think about it), so the addresses of `x` and `fp` are both there.

What you might possibly be getting at however (with "which section of the program are function pointers stored") *maybe* something a bit different: if you assign a value to the pointer-to-function--as in you assign it the address of an actual function-- the *address of the function is contains* will almost certainly be somewhere else, because executable code is located in a different part of system memory than the execution stack.

(The array of ints is allocated entirely on the stack and if you treat `x` as a pointer, it will point into the stack area.)